# How do I determine the best setup for a network setup between 2 houses?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, mesh-networking

My family owns 2 houses that are in a rural area.

My goal is to setup a single network between them with a single ISP (firewifi) via a single router. As well, to make sure that there is a strong wifi signal with in the perimeter of the red, blue, and purple lines in the picture below.

Referencing the picture below, you can see a very crude drawing to show the land. The numbered buildings are the houses that will need the wifi signal inside. They both have electricity. There are outdoor electrical outlets around both homes along the perimeter of each.

Red = 85 meters Blue = 45 meters Purple = 90 meters

There is a lot of trees and Im trying to avoid a lot of new electrical work. Should I use a mesh network? Should I use access points? What things should I be weary of? FYI my family relies upon cell phone calling over wifi, hence why I am using firewifi with a directional antenna.

The

I am a software engineer and a nerd, but Im really at a lose at where to start without spinning my wheels

Any advice, guides, thoughts would be helpful

[image]

Comment: Which building currently has Internet access? Do all the buildings currently have electricity?

Comment: Updated the question and picture. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I've gotten good coverage with a mesh network. You may want five, one in each building close to outside wall.